# How can I parse a file and map input into several subrecords?

Tags: java

I have to start of with saying that I'm a super noob when it comes to Java and programming in general.

My issue:
I have a problem with parsing a `textfile` and putting the data of the file into `subrecords`. The key whether to put the data into a new `subrecord` or not is in my case based on the name of the tag in the file.

Here's an example of a file that I want to `parse/split` into `subrecords`.

SHP
DATA 1
DATA 2
DATA 3
ITEM A
DATA B
DATA C
ITEM A
DATA B
DATA C
SHP

So basically when I encounter the first occurrence of `SHP` I want to create a new `SHP` Class and then map the following tags (DATA in this example) into fields of the new `SHP` Object. However if the next tag is ITEM, I then need to create a new **ITEM Object** in `SHP` and then map the following **DATA** tags until a new ITEM tag is found... What makes it worse is that number of `SHP` tags can also be multiple in the file that I'm parsing.

What I've done so far is to put all the contents of the file into a `ArrayList` and then I iterate over this list and depending of the value of the current "record" I then create a new Object or map the value of the record in the list.
However I get totally lost with all my loops and I need some help! :)

Is there a good way of doing this?
 How can I easily fetch chunks of data from an `ArrayList` and extract and map this into new objects depending on the value of the current record?

I'm thinking that the same questions would appear if you would to create a parser from scratch that maps the data from an `XML` file and puts this into Objects, right?

**Extended version of issue with real examples**

Maybe it's easier if I provide some real examples and real data to illustrate my issue. Initially I just thought that it would make it harder to understand but hopefully this will be easier.

The file and the content:
[Example file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO2f0.png)

So what I have done so far is to create some classes that should represent the data in the file. I even names the fields/variables of the class so that it would be easier for me to map.

Here are the classes:

```
 public class REQUEST {
    public SHIPMENT[] SHIPMENTS;
}
public class SHIPMENT {
    public String IVNO;
    public String CNNAME;
    public String CNADDRESS1;   
    public String CNPC;
    public String CNCITY;

    public PACKAGE[] PACKAGES;
    public ITEM[] ITEMS;    
}

public class PACKAGE {    
    public String GOODSLINE;
    public String GOODSDESCR;
    public String GRWEIGHT;
}

public class ITEM {
    public String ITEMLINE;
    public String ARTNO;
    public String GRWEIGHT;
}
```

And below is the code that I've done that doesn't work properly. I manage to create multiple SHIPMENT's and also create the ITEM's but for some reason the data isn't mapped. I also before calling this mapMethod put the entire content of the file into an ArrayList. One fiel row per record in the ArrayList.

Ok, so here it is in it's total and please be gentle with me :)

```
public REQUEST mapRequest(ArrayList<String> inputfile)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    REQUEST request = new REQUEST();
    ArrayList<SHIPMENT> shipments = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputfile.size(); i++) {

    String recordIdentifier = getRecordIdentifier(inputfile.get(i));
    if (StringUtils.equals(recordIdentifier, "IVNO")) {
        SHIPMENT shipment = new SHIPMENT();
        ArrayList<ITEM> items = new ArrayList<>();

        int j = 0;
        for (j = i; j < inputfile.size(); j++) {

            String currShpRecIdentifier = getRecordIdentifier(inputfile.get(j));
            String nextShpRecIdentifier = StringUtils.EMPTY;
            if (j + 1 < inputfile.size()) {
                nextShpRecIdentifier = getRecordIdentifier(inputfile.get(j + 1));
            }

            try {
                Field field = shipment.getClass().getField(currShpRecIdentifier);
                String shipmentRecordValue = getRecordValue(inputfile.get(j));
                field.set(shipment, shipmentRecordValue);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (StringUtils.equals(nextShpRecIdentifier, "ITEMLINE")) {
                ITEM item = new ITEM();

                int k = 0;
                for (k = j; k < inputfile.size(); k++) {

                    String currItemRecIdentifier = getRecordIdentifier(inputfile.get(k));
                    String nextItemRecIdentifier = StringUtils.EMPTY;
                    if (k + 1 < inputfile.size()) {
                        nextItemRecIdentifier = getRecordIdentifier(inputfile
                                .get(k + 1));
                    }

                    try {
                        Field field = item.getClass().getField(currItemRecIdentifier);
                        String itemRecordValue = getRecordValue(inputfile.get(k));
                        field.set(item, itemRecordValue);
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (StringUtils.equals(nextItemRecIdentifier, "ITEMLINE")) {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                items.add(item);
                j = k;
            }

            if (StringUtils.equals(nextShpRecIdentifier, "IVNO")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        shipment.ITEMS = items.toArray(new ITEM[items.size()]);
        shipments.add(shipment);

        i = j;

    }

}

request.SHIPMENTS = shipments.toArray(new SHIPMENT[shipments.size()]);

return request;
```

}

```
private String getRecordIdentifier(String in) {
    return StringUtils.left(in, 15).trim();
}

private String getRecordValue(String in) {
    return StringUtils.substring(in, 16).trim();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this with loops.  You use a stack and push old elements on to the stack.  I've done this with XML just as you suggest, it works well.  However you have no closing tag for SHP, ITEM, etc. so you'll have to explain how those are "closed" for us.

Comment: The closing tags in this case is actually when the same tag appears again, or end of file. So basically put everything between the tags SHP into an Object and then also create subrecords for each ITEM inside a SHP, it that makes any sense at all...

Comment: You should probably go into more detail.  What classes do you have now, for example, and how do want to process the DATA lines?  But I could probably give an outline how I would do this.

Comment: What do you mean " However if the next tag is ITEM"? If I have SHP DATA DATA ITEM, where does every data go? To the SHP or the ITEM? Give us an example of how you want this to go. I have understood that the data will be assigned to the last found SHP, until you find an item, and all data will be assigned to that item.

Also, if you have SHP DATA ITEM DATA SHP DATA
the last data, goes to the ITEM or SHP? In my example I'm assuming that it goes to the SHP.

Comment: I think he means that SHP DATA DATA, that data is associated with SHP, but after you have ITEM DATA DATA, then that data is associated with the ITEM.  I'm unclear if any ITEM closes ITEM A, or only an ITEM A can close another ITEM A.  Can ITEMs contain other ITEMS?

Comment: I think that there are no closing tags. Just match everything to the last appropriate thing found. And as far as he has described, items can only contain data, while SHP can contain data and items.

Comment: I edited my initial question with some more details and real data and maybe this makes it easier to understand? What makes it worse is that in some cases there could be less or more values in the file so I can use a "fix" number of segments. Sometimes the ITEM could follow with just ARTNO and in some cases ITEM could follow with ARTNO and GRWEIGHT so that's why I tried to check for the next line in the Array and determine the next action.

Comment: You should also explain, how you want this file stored in memory. For example, everything below the ITEMLINE belongs to an ITEM (the last-most recent ITEM), and I'm guessing that this ITEM, belongs to the most recent IVNO? So it would be like that: http://i.imgur.com/TEfgFXwl.png?1

Comment: That is exactly how you illustrated it! And for now I'm only storing this in the memory as a base for later actions (sorting the data and then create various web interface calls with this data). If I could just get the relation/model that you showed in the picture Mr Gkinis into real objects then I'm over the moon with joy! And my second issue is that the code I did is not that easy to read and I get lost with all the loops and such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get where you're having trouble with that.

```
FileReader input = new FileReader(filePathToYourFile);
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
String readLine = null;
String shp = "SHP"; //or define them as "constants" with static final
String item = "ITEM";
String data = "DATA";
ArrayList<SHPType> listOfSHPObjects = new ArrayList<SHPType>();
SHPType lastSHP;
ItemType lastItem;

while ( (readLine = bufRead.readLine()) != null)
{    
    String[] splittedLine = readLine.split(" ");
    if(splittedLine[0].equals(shp))
    { //if it's an SHP, make an SHP object, and add it to a list.
        lastSHP = new SHPType();
        listOfSHPObjects.add(lastshp);
    }
    if(splittedLine[0].equals(data) && lastSHP != null)
    { //if it's a data object, either add it to the property/field/list/collection of the latest SHP, or if you have found an item, add it to the item.
      //of course if you haven't found any SHP objects, discard it, as it doesn't belong anywhere
        if(lastItem == null)
           lastSHP.CollectionThatHoldsData.add(new DataType());
        else
           lastItem.CollectionThatHoldsData.add(new DataType());
    }
    if(splittedLine[0].equals(item) && lastSHP != null)
    {
        //create a new last item and add it to the item list of the last SHP found. New data will be added to this item
        lastItem = new ItemType();
        lastSHP.CollectionThatHoldsItems.add(lastItem);
    }
}
//close the file etc...
```

This assumes that if you find the following:

DATA
ITEM
SHP
etc

The first DATA and ITEM are meaningless. If you want to assign them to the first SHP that you have found, store them in a waitingForSHP arrayList, and as soon as you find the first SHP, add them there.

Also, if you want to create an SHP/Item/Data based on the second value (fe in DATA 5, meaning 5), pass the 5 (splittedLine[1] variable in my example) as an argument to the constructor of the SHPType/ItemType/DataType object. It will be a string, so if you want to pass it as an integer, you will have to convert it ( Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[1]) ).

Comment: I guess the problem lies in actually mapping the relation SHP->ITEM->data and the fact that a SHP can have several ITEM's and also that SHP has fields itself that needs to be mapped. Looking at my latest example (I edited my question) how would you go about solving that?

Comment: My reply is correct for your use case. Your code is overly complicated for no reason. Your classes are correct, although I would recommend using lists over arrays for the ITEMS, PACKAGES fields of SHIPMENT, as well as the SHIPMENTS field of REQUEST. That's because you don't know the  size of the array when you are creating it. Also, try reading the file, line by line, as I am doing in my code (with BufferedReader.readLine() ). You only need 1 loop this way. If you follow my code and change the names to match your classes you're a-ok. If you don't understand something, ask me.